# Sitecore Azure - Swap option

Tags: azure

Which Sitecore and Azure SDK version supports swap option as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something I have been using since Sitecore Azure version 2 at least. It's my understanding that having a production and a staging slots is one of the original features of Azure Cloud services.
So even without having tested all of them I'm going to say: It's available on all Sitecore Azure versions.

Comment: Adding a footnote that Sitecore Azure is retired and discontinued as of Sitecore 8.2.  Utilization of Azure Web Apps natively is supported as of Sitecore 8.2 Update 1.